# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive on calling asmx web service on remote machine

Tags: c#, asmx, tls1.2

I am currently upgrading dot net framework in my application from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 to support TLS1.2.
And I am getting an error **The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.** on calling asmx web service on remote machine.

Below is the complete stack trace

> Error       : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a receive. Stack Trace : at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.TS2IPAccount.Proxy.HsAccountService.GetIssuedCards(GetIssuedCardsRequest
>   GetIssuedCardsRequest) in
>   C:\Upgrade3\healthcare\ClientProxy_Comp\ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.Template\TS2IPAccount\ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.TS2IPAccount\proxy\TS2IPAccountClientProxy.cs:line
>   863    at
>   ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.TS2IPAccount.TS2IPAccountProxy.GetIssuedCards(String
>   clientMsgID, String primeBankNumber, String cardNumber) in
>   C:\Upgrade3\healthcare\ClientProxy_Comp\ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.Template\TS2IPAccount\ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.TS2IPAccount\TS2IPAccountProxy.cs:line
>   2636 Message     :
>   ProCard.RTMS.ClientProxy.TS2IPAccount.TS2IPAccountProxyERROR (probably
>   from RTMS itself):System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot
>   communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm    at
>   System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface
>   SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse
>   credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)

Below is the code where I am getting the error.

```
public GetIssuedCardsInfo GetIssuedCards
{
    HsAccountService proxy = new HsAccountService();
    GetIssuedCardsResponse resp = new GetIssuedCardsResponse();
    resp = proxy.GetIssuedCards(req);
}
```

So I am getting error at the response. 
When I am sending the soap request using SOAP Ui tool and calling our remote asmx web service I am getting the response correctly but I am not getting the response from our application.

I am currently stuck and not able to find the solution for this particular issue. Please help.

Comment: You don't need >4.5.2 to use TLS1.2; it's just not enabled by default. Check the following out; it has all you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: Thank You.. Setting <httpRuntime targetFrameWork="4.7.2" /> worked for me.